# regular expression required at least one space in any position

Tags: regex

I have a form with an input field and pattern attribute that is case sensitive, but I also need to have at least one blank space or more (required) in any position

```
<input type="text" name="name" class="field" required pattern="[\wà-úÀ-Ú]" />
```

Comment: Would it allow only one whitespace?

Comment: Strange requirement, but this would do it: `.*\s.*`

Comment: `.* .*` would allow only a single space as well

Comment: obligatorily at least one

Comment: Do you actually mean any whitespace (tabs, newlines, carriage returns, etc), or just a normal space?

Comment: just a normal space, its is <input type="text"

Answer (score 2):

If you want your field to allow only one whitespace then your pattern is `.* .*`

But if you don't want to allow only whitespace, your pattern is `(.+ .*)|(.* .+)`

If you don't want the space to appear in the beginning or end, but always preceded and succeeded by a letter, then your pattern is `.+ .+`

PS: Note the space character in all the patterns

Comment: I have a form with an input field and pattern attribute that is case sensitive, but I also need to have at least one blank space or more (required) in any position

Comment: The pattern that I mentioned checks for only one space, if you want one or more, just add + after the space. Since a space can also mean a tab, you can replace space with \s, so your final pattern is `(.+\s+.*)|(.*\s+.+)`

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, sorry for my bad English, I use Google translator, can not contain numbers or special characters, accented letters can contain. Required \s{1,} and letters

Answer (score 0):

Match all characters followed by least a whitespace character *(\r\n\t\f\v )* then all characters. This will match when there is a whitespace anywhere in the text.

```
.*\s.*
```

The wildcard can be replaced with a character set.

```
[\wà-úÀ-Ú]*\s[\wà-úÀ-Ú]*
```

Comment: No need to have the + quantifier, or the square brackets.

Comment: I have a form with an input field and pattern attribute that is case sensitive, but I also need to have at least one blank space or more (required) in any position